# What's the meaning of "Sollensaussagen"?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading the introduction to Kant's *Grundlegung der Metaphysik der Sitten* and came across this line

> In den beiden Schriften untersucht Kant die Voraussetzungen und die Möglichkeit moralisch verbindlicher **Sollensaussagen**.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a definition for this word anywhere, as if it didn't even exist.

Comment: I'm tripping there even as a native German reader, mostly because of the Fugen- (or Genitive-?) S. The recent speling reforms encourage hyphenating when it improves understanding, see https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich. If we hyphenate *Sollens-Aussagen* it might clear the issue up.

Comment: One complication with this word is that it contains a number of misleading candidates for composition: "(das) Sollen, "(des) Sollens", "(die) Sau", "saus[e[n]]", "sagen". "Saussagen"? "Sollensaus"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In philosophy, esp. in moral philosophy, the distinction between *Seinsaussagen* and *Sollensaussagen* is fundamental. *Seinsaussagen* are assertions about how the world **is** (*to be* is *sein* in German). *Sollensaussagen* are statements about how the world **shall** (*shall* or *ought* is *sollen* in German) be (in moral terms). The distinction is important, esp. for Kant, because it is impossible to infer Sollenssaussagen from Seinsaussagen. Such an inference is called *Seins-Sollens-Fehlschluss* (in english: *is-ought-fallacy* or [*is-ought-problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem)) or a violation of *Hume's Law*, after David Hume. This distinction of those two different kinds of assertions is very much part of the core of Kant's moral philosophy.

The english word for *Sollenssaussage* is **moral judgement** or **normative statement** and the english word for *Seinsaussage* is **positive statement**.

The given sentence

> In den beiden Schriften untersucht Kant die Voraussetzungen und die Möglichkeit moralisch verbindlicher Sollensaussagen.

could be translated into

> *In both works, Kant is exploring the prerequisites and possibilities of morally binding statements about how the world shall be.*

or into

> *In both works, Kant is exploring the prerequisites and possibilities of morally binding normative statements.*

Comment: Note: **positive statements** may also called **empirical claims** or **empirical statements** in English.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy First, I thought so, too. But I do not think, that _empirical_ is strictly synonym to _positive_, because _empirical_ is an epistemological category, i.e. it is saying about how a certain fact can be known (by perception), and _positive_ is not necessarily an epistemological category: ...

Comment: ... There might be positions which claim that there are _positive statements_ whose logical value cannot be clarified by perception, so they are not _empirical statements_. They would, for instance say that the claim "God does not exist" is a positive statement (not a normative one), but it is not an empirical statement. That's the reason why I hesitate to say that _positive statements_ may also be _called empirical statements_. But that is maybe too much philosophy for a platform which focusses on language, not on philosophy itself.

Comment: "In philosophy, esp. in moral philosophy, the distinction between Seinsaussagen and Sollensaussagen is fundamental." - interesting vocabulary observation: In engineering, essentially the very same concepts exist, but rather than "sein" and "sollen", the words used are "ist" and "soll".

Answer (score 9):

German is full of noun compounds that are not listed in dictionaries. The meaning of such compounds is hopefully derivable from the meaning of the parts. Let's see whether it works in this case.

> *Sollen*: (noun derived from the verb by conversion) roughly *obligation, duty*
>   *Aussage*: *statement*
>   *Sollensaussage*: *statement about obligation or duty*

<sub>Note: I wanted to show what I think is a sound strategy when encountering unfamiliar compounds. As Jonathan Scholbach's answer shows, technical terms often have a meaning that cannot be derived (although the derived meaning actually provides a solid basis for understanding the technical meaning in this case). A humorous example would be *Spannung* *(suspense, excitement, tension)*, which in Physics means *voltage*. This is the reason why there are specialised dictionaries.</sub>